# Any good example on Implementation of spring.net + NHibernate + Repository pattern

Tags: nhibernate, repository-pattern, spring.net

Are there any good example on implementation of Spring.net with NHibernate and Repository pattern?

Currently I'm going through below url's.

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-web

Answer (score 0):

It uses Castle Windsor rather than Spring, but the [Sharp Architecture](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/) is a good example of using the Repository-Pattern with NHibernate (behind an MVC app).

Comment: @Richardson,

My current project is on MOSS and SQL. Hence, can I use Sharp Architecture's Nhibernate and Repository benefits only.
Also, is there any good example for this implementation.
Thanks.